# Does the operand of unary* operator expect a prvalue

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer

```cpp
int main(){
  int a = 0;
  auto ptr = &a;
  auto&& rf = *ptr;
}
```

Consider the above code, when glvalue `ptr` is used to as the operand of unary* operator, Is it be required a lvalue-to-rvalue conversion that would applied for it? I.E, Does the operand of unary* operator expect a prvalue?

#### Question 1:

[expr.unary.op#1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.unary.op#1)

> The unary * operator performs indirection: the expression to which it is applied shall be a pointer to an object type, or a pointer to a function type and the result is an lvalue referring to the object or function to which the expression points. If the type of the expression is “pointer to T”, the type of the result is “T”. [ Note: Indirection through a pointer to an incomplete type (other than cv void) is valid. The lvalue thus obtained can be used in limited ways (to initialize a reference, for example); this lvalue must not be converted to a prvalue, see [conv.lval].  — end note ]

What kind of value categories does  operands of unary* operator expect.

---

Beside this operator, It seems to the most operators in [expr] is not specified what kind of value categories its operands expect.

[expr#9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr#9)

> Whenever a glvalue expression appears as an operand of an operator that expects a prvalue for that operand, the lvalue-to-rvalue, array-to-pointer, or function-to-pointer standard conversions are applied to convert the expression to a prvalue. [ Note: Because cv-qualifiers are removed from the type of an expression of non-class type when the expression is converted to a prvalue, an lvalue expression of type const int can, for example, be used where a prvalue expression of type int is required.  — end note ].

The quote above is so unclear.

#### Question 2:

As aforementioned, the most operators in [expr] is not specified what kind of value categories its operands expect. So It it a defect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, it is [CWG1642](http://wg21.link/cwg1642):

> **1642. Missing requirements for prvalue operands**
>
> Although the note in 6.10 [basic.lval] paragraph 1 states that
>
> > The discussion of each built-in operator in Clause 8 [expr] indicates the category of the value it yields and the value categories of the operands it expects
>
> in fact, many of the operators that take prvalue operands do not make that requirement explicit. Possible approaches to address this failure could be a blanket statement that an operand whose value category is not stated is assumed to be a prvalue; adding prvalue requirements to each operand description for which it is missing; or changing the description of the usual arithmetic conversions to state that they imply the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, which would cover the majority of the omissions.

In particular, [expr.unary.op]/1 wording should be fixed by [this PR](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/pull/3945).

Comment: Maybe , the first approach is the most possible way, such as at the begin of [expr] section, `Note, Except as specified in somewhere, all  these operators that described in [expr] expect prvalue as their operands`, such would be a bit  modification.

Comment: When I started read [expr.unary.op]/1 , I have the same misunderstanding with you as you said in [github](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/pull/3945#issuecomment-615839611), However after reading [basic.compound#3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.compound#3) again and again, I find the type of expression is T does not mean , the expression point to an object of type T.

Comment: @jackX _the type of expression is T does not mean , the expression point to an object of type T._ And...?

Comment: For example, when a pointer point to an object of type int, Now  after I applied `reinterpret_­cast` to the pointer will make the result has the type I specified within `static_cast`(such as double), however according to [expr.static.cast#13](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.static.cast#13), the pointer still point to the original object(because pointer-interconvertible rule, so pointer value unchanged), It's just the type have changed, hence, as said in [expr.unary.op], the result is the lvalue that refer to the object the expression point to, but the type is `double` here.

Comment: @jackX I don't understand why are you explaining this to me. Where did I demonstrate that I don't know this?

Comment: No, I didn't mean you don' know this. I just want to say the rule in [expr.unary.op] can cause misunderstanding and not easy to read it correctly , as you mentioned in github.

Comment: Sorry, I have not the whole sentence in github, could you cite the changed sentence here, I will read it.

Comment: @jackX you can see the changes in the [Files changed](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/pull/3945/files) tab

Comment: I have a suggestion, that is,  `where T is an object or function type`, could it be modified to `where T is type of objects or functions`, My reason is `objects` or `functions` can denote the category because an object or a function seems to be a specified object or function. Forgive my carp.

Comment: Or, I think we can introduce a concept that is static type or dynamic type of an object or function the pointer point to in [basic.compound#3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.compound#3) and Here We can say that T denotes static type of the object or function  to which the operand point. and the result is a lvalue that refer to an object or  function the operand actually point to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217006/discussion-between-language-lawyer-and-jack-x).